# Render unicode characters in react native using variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, unicode

I'm trying to render some Arabic text which is in the form of Unicode.

I have already tried to render this using Text component like

```
const arabic  = "&#1587;&#1615;&#1576;&#1618;&#1581;&#1614;&#1575;&#1606;&#1614; &#1575;&#1604;&#1604;&#1607;&#1616; &#1608;&#1614;&#1576;&#1616;&#1581;&#1614;&#1605;&#1618;&#1583;&#1616;&#1607;&#1616;"


render(){
 return(
  <Text>
   {arabic}
  </Text>
 )
}
```

it renders the Unicode as it is, but writing it this way

```
render(){
 return(
  <Text>

   &#1587;&#1615;&#1576;&#1618;&#1581;&#1614;&#1575;&#1606;&#1614;  
   #1575;&#1604;&#1604;&#1607;&#1616; 
 &#1608;&#1614;&#1576;&#1616;&#1581;&#1614;&#1605;&#1618;&#1583;&#1616; 
 &#1607;&#1616;

  </Text>
 )
}
```

renders the correct output

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want to store unicode characters / html entities in a variable, you need to replace the html entity with the unicode number.

For example:

```
const arabic = "&#1587;";
```

needs to be replaced with:

```
const arabic  = "\u0633";
```

The are several unicode tables online where you can translate your html entity to the raw unicode number.

**Working example:**

https://snack.expo.io/BJp-jL004

**UPDATE with second approach:**

Instead of a manual translation of the html entities to unicode numbers, you can use the npm module [html-entities](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities). Here the biggest advantage is, that you can use the regular `<Text>` Component to render your characters.

Here is an example:

```
import { Html5Entities } from 'html-entities'; 
const arabic  = "&#1587;&#1615;&#1576;&#1618;&#1581;&#1614;&#1575;&#1606;&#1614; &#1575;&#1604;&#1604;&#1607;&#1616; &#1608;&#1614;&#1576;&#1616;&#1581;&#1614;&#1605;&#1618;&#1583;&#1616;&#1607;&#1616;"

render() {
    const entities = new Html5Entities();
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <View>
        <Text> {entities.decode(arabic)} </Text>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
```

**Output:**

[image: demo]

**Working example:**

https://snack.expo.io/Hk5b3IykS

Answer (score 2):

Solution provided by [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6278661/tim) was correct but in my case, there was a collection of Unicode characters provided by some service

```
&#1587;&#1615;&#1576;&#1618;&#1581;&#1614;&#1575;&#1606;&#1614;  
   #1575;&#1604;&#1604;&#1607;&#1616; 
 &#1608;&#1614;&#1576;&#1616;&#1581;&#1614;&#1605;&#1618;&#1583;&#1616; 
 &#1607;&#1616;
```

so it was a hectic process to convert individual unicode character and then render it .
there is simple workaorund for this,
[react-native-htmlview](https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-htmlview)

```
import HTMLView from 'react-native-htmlview';

export default class Myclass extends Componet{

 render(){

  const arabic  = "&#1587;&#1615;&#1576;&#1618;&#1581;&#1614;&#1575;&#1606;&#1614; &#1575;&#1604;&#1604;&#1607;&#1616; &#1608;&#1614;&#1576;&#1616;&#1581;&#1614;&#1605;&#1618;&#1583;&#1616;&#1607;&#1616;"

  return(

     <HTMLView
      value={"<div>" +arabic+ "</div>"}
      />

  )

 }

}
```

which renders the desired out put

[image: desired output]

Answer (score 2):

you also can just copy the symbol and past in your code - it will work:

```
 <Text>• one upper case</Text>
 <Text>✔ one lower case</Text>
```